# PHP Form code mangled

Tags: php, javascript

I am generating a simple form with php. The following code has been reduced to showcase the problem.

```
<?php
$blah = "<h1>Well</h1>"; $test = "<h2>Done</h2>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="fetchlayers.js"></script>';
$formcode = "<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data \">"
          . "<label for=\"file\">Filename:</label>"
          . "<input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" id=\"file\"/> <br />"
          . "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" "
          .    "onclick=\"setTimeout(function() { sendInfo(\"$blah\", \"$test\"); },1250);\" />"
          . "</form>";

echo "<h1>hello</h1>
<div id='form'>
$formcode
</div>";
```

This results in this html code

```
<h1>hello</h1>
<div id="form">
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data ">
<label for="file">Filename:</label><input name="file" id="file" type="file">
<br><input name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="setTimeout(function() { sendInfo(" type="submit"><h1>Well</h1>", "<h2>Done</h2>"); },1250);" /&gt;
</form>
```

Somehow the form code for type=submit is ending up after my call to sendinfo(). Why?

Comment: How are you seeing the result? When I run the script it works fine for me.

Comment: The others are, of course, right about using single quotes in the JS though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be an escaping issues:

```
<?php
$blah = "<h1>Well</h1>"; $test = "<h2>Done</h2>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="fetchlayers.js"></script>';
$formcode = "<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data \"><label for=\"file\">Filename:</label><input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" id=\"file\"/> <br /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"setTimeout(function() { sendInfo('$blah', '$test'); },1250);\" /></form>";

echo "<h1>hello</h1>
<div id='form'>
". $formcode . "
</div>";
```

The javascript in onclick needs single quotes or it has to use &quot;.

Comment: There's a typo where the first single-quote is supposed to be:  sendInfo(;$blah', '$test');

Answer (score 4):

It's because of your quotes in the onclick. Use single quotes instead:

```
"onclick=\"setTimeout(function() { sendInfo('$blah', '$test'); }, 1250);\" "
```

The way it is now, your onclick attribute actually reads like this:

```
onclick="setTimeout(function() { sendInfo("
```